# Compare strings character by character using iterators in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, iterator

I have to create a compering function using string iterators and recursion. This is what I have

```
enum class Order
{
    LT, GT, EQ
};

Order compare(std::string::iterator a, std::string::iterator b)
{
    if (*a < *b)
        return Order::LT;
    else if (*a > *b)
        return Order::GT;
    else
        compare(a + 1, b + 1);
}
```

If I compare "axx" and "app", it'll return LessThan and I don't know why. Also, I don't know how to compare if next iterators will be null.

Comment: In general, the function would accept end iterators for each string as well.

Comment: Doing this using recursion seems like a bad choice.

Comment: [Ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know what's returned in the else case.

Comment: You also need more than the 2 iterators to be able to detect the end of the strings

Comment: Just so you know: `std:.string` overloads the [spaceship operator `<=>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) that does almost the same. Just in case you want to use the built-in version but didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the value of the recursive call.

```
Order compare(std::string::iterator a, std::string::iterator b)
{
    if (*a < *b)
        return Order::LT;
    else if (*a > *b)
        return Order::GT;
    else
        return compare(a + 1, b + 1);
}
```

Comment: What happens if the strings are identical?

Comment: If they are identical we'll end up trying to dereference the end iterator and get UB.

Comment: Ok, that seems relevant to the answer, don't you think?

Comment: Maybe you're right. I somehow got the idea that OP wasn't really done and wanted to figure that part out for themselves.

Comment: Solving it is nice, but you should alt least warn them that they're not done yet. Otherwise you're just going to get a "Still doesn't work." comment.